# PrimeNG confirmPopup target issue "The expected type comes from property 'target' which is declared here on type 'Confirmation'"

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using primeNg angular library and facing issues with confirmPopup component.

Following is my html code

```
      <p-confirmPopup> </p-confirmPopup>
      <p-button (click)="confirm($event)" icon="pi pi-trash" label="Clear"></p-button>
```

ts file:

```
confirm(event: Event) {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      target: event.target, //issue here
      key:'yes-no-confirmation',
      message: 'Are you sure?',
      icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
      accept: () => this.clearFilter()
      ,
      reject: () => {
        //reject action
      }
    });
  }
```

I get the following error

```
Error: src/app/pages/report/filters/filters.component.ts:38:7 - error TS2322: Type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to type 'EventTarget | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'EventTarget | undefined'.

38       target: event.target,
         ~~~~~~

  node_modules/primeng/api/confirmation.d.ts:21:5
    21     target?: EventTarget;
           ~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'target' which is declared here on type 'Confirmation'
```

I have taken code from [PrimeNG documentation of confirmPopup](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/confirmpopup)

what is worng?

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved this issue by adding Type Assertion after `event.target` like this:

```
target: event.target as EventTarget,  // Type Assertion with the 'as' keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs, you are missing a on* prefix at p-button

[image]

Fix:

```
<p-button (onClick)="confirm($event)" icon="pi pi-trash" label="Clear"></p-button>
```

Comment: tried it. didn't solve the issue. 
its about something in ts file. had it been onClick on click the function wouldn't have been called. but, the issue here is in the function definition.

Comment: try re-serving the application or by replacing `p-button` with `button`

Comment: @Abhijit Please provide sample stackbliz code. It will easy to check  for anyone.